# How to 'skip' npm install in travis build?

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

The goal is to speed up the travis build.
I read some [articles](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/speeding-up-the-build/#Caching-the-dependencies) how to cache dependencies, but it does not make any difference.

So, is it possible to instal npm packages only once in order to save time?

Comment: did you try `npm_skip_install` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the installation step by overwriting the default install behavior. Add this to your `travis.yml`:

```
install: true
```

See the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#customizing-the-installation-step) for more information.